# CSS Media Queries Not Working iPad landscape only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad, media-queries

a sincere thank you for your time before I start.

I am unable to target an iPad using CSS Media Queries in Landscape Mode.  Portrait mode works without issue and similar queries work on the iPhone.  I am using bootstrap.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

Does not work as expected; however,

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

and

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

work fine in Portrait mode only.  When searching this I could only find people describing the problem and no solutions.  I'm open to any other work around or even a link to point me in the right direction. Again, maybe this is a bootstrap specific issue?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have the proper 'viewport' within the documents head? Try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1">`

Comment: Updated viewport line: 
"<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1">" 
and added 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
for now
/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}
with the same result

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though there are a few differences between your CSS and the CSS [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/). Notably, you don't seem to have `and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)` in your CSS and the device-widths are much different for different iPad versions. Can you try some of the CSS in the link and see if that works?

Comment: Updated viewport line from the comment above
"<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1">" 
and added 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
for now
/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}
with the same result, again works in portrait, thanks for the reply sir :)